# Webservice not able to parse JSON Request from a PHP file

Tags: php, json, rest, post

I'm trying to access a webservice. I'm already using this webservice from an android app but now I need to access some functions from a php document. If I use chromes advanced rest client application for testing it works fine if I select the `POST` option and `application/x-www-form-urlencode` as content-type. But when I try to access the webservice from my PHP file I get the response from the server that it can't find the value "tag". This is the code:

```
$data = array( 'tag' => 'something');

$options = array('http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'content' => $data,
'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode")
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$url = 'myurl';
$result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
$response = json_decode($result);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = http_build_query( array( 'tag' => 'something') );
```

As defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), "Content" value must be a string: **http_build_query** generate the URL-encoded query string you need.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried with `http_build_query` but still my `$_POST['tag']` call in my server side code is empty :(

Comment: Ah I found the mistake: I had a typo in my header definition: T of Type should be small and it is urlencoded not urlencode. This in addition with `http_build_query` works! Thanks!